# How to get a new dataframe from a date range, showing everyday in daterange while including all my columns

Tags: python, pandas, powerbi-desktop

I have a for loop looping all my rows and include columns start and end dates, then another loop within the first loop which takes the range between my dates, so that it takes everyday in my ranges. I need to make a new df which show everyday in these ranges and keeps the rest of my columns.

```
ID       Name      Manager     Client     Start        End       Rate       
5123     O Kin     D Jam       P Diddy    2-1-2019     6-6-2019  100        
1234     D Rus     A Gio       P Diddy    3-4-2018     4-7-2019  100    
3456     R Asd     G Nee       P Diddy    1-1-2018     5-5-2019  150    
6643     M Ben     C Gee       Tupeeee    3-3-2019     4-5-2019  120
```

The purpose of this is that when i import to power bi, My original dataset only shows start and end dates, so i cannot filter. I need to be able to to import the entire date range or perhaps the unique of it?(help) so that i can filter out month, day, year. My bus_days below shows 12000 days workdays and i only have 50 rows. Should i import with the rest of my columns or as a date dataframe? These are my required columns:
Index(['ID', 'Name', 'Manager', 'Client,
       'Days', 'Holidays', 'Rate']

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():

    busdays = []
    start = pd.to_datetime(df['Start_Date'][i])
    end = pd.to_datetime(df['End_Date'][i])
    holidays = df['Holidays'][i]       
    df['days'][i] = workdays(start, end, holidays)
    reve[i] = day[i] * rate[i]
    reve[i] = rev[i]*df['Percentage'][i]//100
    day_range =  pd.bdate_range(start, end)


    for day_ in day_range:
        date_str = datetime.datetime(day_.year, day_.month, day_.day, 0, 
        0)
        date_str = day_.strftime('%m, %d, %Y')
        date_ = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, "%m, %d, 
        %Y").date()
        busdays.append(date_str)
```

I need:

```
    ID      Name    Manager Client  Date          Rate
0   5123    O Kin   D James P Diddy 2-1-2019      100   
1   5123    O Kin   D James P Diddy 3-1-2019      100   
2   5123    O Kin   D James P Diddy 4-1-2019      150   
3   5213    O Kin   D James P Diddy 5-1-2019      120
```

i have: the dates for everyday, ie. busdays(work days) from the code

I need: the rest of the columns:
ID      Name    Manager Client  Date  Rate

Random dates in my code are start and end dates ranging from 01- 01-2018 to 31-12-2019. Total busdays i have is around 12000 from an initial dataset of 50 rows. I need to fill up other columns to match the dates
Any suggestions will be appreciated.